# MySQL measure full table scan time

Tags: mysql

I have a 5TB table. All I want to know is how much time it takes to do a full table scan. I don't care about the data getting returned. I tried to run `select * from mytable;` but for some reason the client got killed. Not sure if it is caused by some sort of timeout or too much data to handle. Is there a reliable way to get the time consumption of the query? Not sure if this is gonna help but my table schema looks like this: `create table datatable (a integer, name varchar(200), class varchar(200), reason varchar(200));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
set profiling = 1;
select count(*) from datatable where a = 1;
show profiles;
```

Assuming you don't have any indexes on column `a` this should force a full table scan and it will return only one row, with minimum overhead for data transfer.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem when I tried to do it with mysql workbench(as it gives execution time) but connection to mysql server failed whenever the data was large.

So since I was using java and springboot, I made an Api, service and repository for it to interact with the database where I had to make classes as entity for each table
and then I just let the spring jpa give command to mysql to scan the required database, I used nanosecond library of java to calculate time difference and converted that into seconds. It went quite smooth. I understand that some extra time is added due to being spring jpa in between me executing the call to run the scan and mysql database actual scan, but I think that is very negligible.

So maybe you can do the same in your preference of language or framework.